# Files not restored after git reset --hard

Tags: git

I am trying to rollback all my commits and files to a specific commit. I want to get rid of all the changes I did and all the files that were created from that specific commit onwards.

I tried rolling back using:

```
git checkout #commit_to_restore_to
git reset --hard #commit_to_restore_to
```

I get a confirmation that `HEAD is now at #commit_to_restore_to "Commit_message"`

However, my files are exactly the same as before. How can I rollback all my files?

I am on Ubuntu 12.10.

Here is more information:

```
$ git status
<<fill this in>>

# git diff --name-status #commit_to_restore_to  #provide real commit number please.
<<fill this in too>>
```

Comment: were those files commited? what does `git status` say?

Comment: @Fredrik it says #not currently on any branch. 
Nothing to commit (working directory clean)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I feel so embarrassed. The files were changing, the problem is that the folders weren't. Since my .gitignore has (e.g.) pyc files, the folders that I had created post commit were still there because they had those files in it. I was just doing an ls on the dir and going insane for since the same tree structure kept showing up.

Sorry about that and thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The easy way to rewrite a branch ref is

> `git branch -f master`*`commit`*

if you're on that branch at the moment you can

> `git checkout -B master`*`commit`*

Comment: This still does not restore my files

Answer (score 0):

If you `checkout` a commit then you have the contents of your repository as of that commit in your working directory.  There is thus nothing to `reset`.  There would be something if you did instead:

```
$ git checkout <commit>
# muck with files; do some other git stuff
$ git reset --hard <commit>
```

In the above case `reset` will actually do something.

It sounds like what you really want is to forget everything after commit and then to continue development.  If so, this works (assume you are on the `master` branch):

```
$ git checkout -b tmp-branch <commit>
$ git branch -d master
$ git branch -m tmp-branch master
```

and you will want to be careful with the above.

Comment: This did not work...the previous files are still there unmodified :(

Comment: In your original question post the result of 'git status'.  Also post the exact results of 'git diff --name-status <commit>'

Answer (score 0):

Careful!  When you did `git checkout SHA` you ended up on a floating branch.  `git status` should say something like:

```
# Not currently on any branch.
```

There was also a warning from `git checkout`.  If you wanted to reset your `master` branch with `git reset --hard SHA` you want to move back to that branch first with `git checkout master`.

Answer (score 0):

For me as workarounds I found:

```
git rm --cached -r . 

git reset --hard
```

and sometimes only:
 `git ls-files -m | xargs -I {} git update-index --assume-unchanged {}`

But this didn't fix the root problem.

**I found that a setting from `.gitattributes` generated the problem**:

I had `*.bat text eol=crlf` that was enforcing bat files in Windows having eol=crlf.

I commented that setting:

`#*.bat text eol=crlf`